# Get form values after form has been submitted and redirected to page

Tags: php, html

I'm using a POST method for my form. If my form is submitted the page the form is on reloads and because `$_POST['submit']` is set it will then process my form through my validation.

If for some reason the input is invalid (missing required fields, wrong password requirements etc). The session object stores the message and a redirect takes place to the page where the form is located.

Due to this redirect my `$_POST` values vanish. Should I store all the `$_POST` values in my session object or is there a more convenient way of keeping track of the user submitted fields?

Comment: Can you validate on Front-end/Back-end before doing the submit post?

Comment: Use a FE framework like http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/, which won't let the form submit without correct values, then make sure to do backend validation before redirect?

Comment: This does look good, but I dislike using such plugins as a lot of stuff you're not going to use is added to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You avoid this kind of trap by having the form submit to itself, or at least including the form on the processing page. This is nice because

```
if isset($_POST['submit']) {
    // do your validation
    if ($valid) {
        // show success, redirect elsewhere, etc 
    } else {
        // include the form, using the supplied $_POST values
        // use the validation flags you raised to display form errors
    }


} else {   // if no $_POST values exist
    // initialize $_POST values 
    // include the form
}
```

Comment: Mhm, I was thinking about this and tried it, but I have some error somewhere. Is this option better than storing the values in session?

Comment: Nijn are you sure that the action attribute points to a correct path to the processing page?

Comment: The processing page is the same as the page where the form is listed. So yes.

Comment: @Nijn only store in session what you need, and form vars are generally single-purpose, so I recommend trying the above and correcting any errors you come across.